# Assert that two lists of objects are equal in django testing

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

Is there a way to check that two lists of objects are equal in django tests.

lets say I have some model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug
```

and I run this simple test:

```
def test_equal_list_fail(self):
    tag_list = []
    for tag in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        tag_list.append(Tag.objects.create(slug=tag))

    tags = Tag.objects.all()

    self.assertEqual(tag_list, tags)
```

this fails with:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_equal_list_fail (userAccount.tests.ProfileTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/tests.py", line 155, in test_equal_list_fail
    self.assertEqual(tag_list, tags)
AssertionError: [<Tag: a>, <Tag: b>, <Tag: c>] != [<Tag: a>, <Tag: b>, <Tag: c>]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this will work:

```
def test_equal_list_passes(self):
    tag_list = []
    for tag in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        tag_list.append(Tag.objects.create(slug=tag))

    tags = Tag.objects.all()

    for tag_set in zip(tags, tag_list):
        self.assertEqual(*tag_set)
```

However, This fails:

```
def test_equal_list_fail(self):
    tag_list = []
    for tag in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        tag_list.append(Tag.objects.create(slug=tag))

    tags = Tag.objects.all()

    for tag_set in zip(tags, tag_list):
        print "\n"
        print tag_set[0].slug + "'s pk is %s" % tag_set[0].pk
        print tag_set[1].slug + "'s pk is %s" % tag_set[1].pk
        print "\n"
        self.assertIs(*tag_set)
```

with:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.......

a's pk is 1
a's pk is 1

F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_equal_list_fail (userAccount.tests.ProfileTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/tests.py", line 160, in test_equal_list_fail
    self.assertIs(*tag_set)
AssertionError: <Tag: a> is not <Tag: a>
```

**Is this expected behavior?**

**Edit** in response to comment
This type of comparison works:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

>>> one = Obj(1)
>>> two = Obj(2)
>>> a = [one, two]
>>> b = [one, two]
>>> a == b
True
```

Why is the test failing for the other arrays?

Comment: The reason the zip() works is because the text representation of your tag is the slug, and that's what you are comparing with.

Comment: Why wouldn't comparing the arrays do the same? I'll edit my question to show an example

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## To test two lists

use: [assertSequenceEqual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertSequenceEqual)

Because, in this case, `tags = Tag.objects.all()` generates a `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` where as `tag_list.append(...)` creates a list.

Other options in different situations are:

- assertListEqual(a, b)
- assertTupleEqual(a, b)
- assertSetEqual(a, b)
- assertDictEqual(a, b)

## Why `<Tag: a> is not <Tag: a>`

The tags are the same model, but they've been loaded into different places in memory

```
for tag_set in zip(tags, tag_list):
    print "\n"
    print tag_set[0].slug + "'s pk is %s" % tag_set[0].pk + ' id is: ' + id(tag_set[0])
    print tag_set[1].slug + "'s pk is %s" % tag_set[1].pk + ' id is: ' + id(tag_set[1])
    print "\n"
    self.assertIs(*tag_set)
```

returns

```
.......

a's pk is 1 id is: 4522000208
a's pk is 1 id is: 4522228112

F.
```

Therefore, `is` will retrun `False`

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to test is if the tags created have the same slugs as those in your test list.

For that, fetch only the slug as a list with [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), and then compare that:

```
assertEqual(Tag.objects.values_list('slug', flat=True), ['a','b','c'])
```

I have to say, this isn't quite a useful test because you are checking django orm functionality, which has already been tested quite well.

Your tests should check for specifics of your own application.

Comment: hmm `values_list` is a good trick to know, +1 for that. I agree, in this case this is a useless test. I just wanted a simple example to show the test failing. My actual test isn't this trivial. I'd prefer not to use slugs because I want to check that the actual models are equal, but I suppose that it could be done with their `pk`s

Comment: Don't use `pk` because those are incremental (most likely) and two primary keys would not be equal (they shouldn't, if they are you have bigger problems). If the desired functionality is to _prevent_ duplicates, then use [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#unique-together) to help enforce this at the database level.

Comment: Can you expand on how to use `unique_together` in this case? It's not clear to me.